# My instance of Oracle 12c is using up alot of space and I am not sure why How to free up space

Tags: oracle

I am developer, not an Oracle admin. We have an Oracle 12c instance that is used only by developers. It is currently using up most of the disk space on the machine. The C:\app\OracleUser\product]12.1.0\db_home\RDBMS directory is currently 121 GB. There are a number of files that start with ARC in that directory. What are these files and how can I make more room? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Those ARC files are your [Archived Redo Logs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/archredo.htm). In a production environment (or one that you're concerned about recovering) they're an important part of your backup strategy.

In a disposable development environment, they can be a bit of a nuisance though.

Short term fix - log into RMAN and do this to get rid of everything over a day old:

```
RMAN> DELETE NOPROMPT COPY OF ARCHIVELOG ALL COMPLETED BEFORE 'SYSDATE-1';
```

Long term fix for a development environment that you don't care about backing up - this will disable archive logs:

```
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE
STARTUP MOUNT
ALTER DATABASE NOARCHIVELOG;
ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
```